# Ionic platform Config file changes

Tags: ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm trying to create push notification app using Ionic. When i build the app the following line is removed from res/xml/config.xml file in android platform.

`<feature name="PushPlugin">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.plugin.gcm.PushPlugin" />
</feature>`

Please help me understand the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install the Push Notification plugin or are you adding this line manually?

Every time you build the config.xml is overwritten. As far as I know each plugin includes all the  and  it needs to function properly, and they are added to the config.xml and AndroidManifest respectively when you build your app.

So if you've installed the PushPlugin, the line will be added automatically. If you're adding the line manually before building it will be overwritten.

In case the line is not after all the above, try uninstalling and installing the plugin, then running

```
     ionic prepare android
```

before running the build again.

Comment: Thanks for the response and it is resolved. I'd to revert cordova version to 5.0.0 from 5.1.1 and reinstall push notification plugin again

Comment: @user3368953 The cordova version should not be an issue, it is most probably the plugin that wasn't properly installed. Installing plugins is a bit tricky without plugman. I hope my answer helped anyway and I would appreciate if you could mark it as answer if it served its purpose :D